# File system went read only after adding ssh key

Tags: ssh, filesystems, ubuntu-14.04

My file system went read-only. After reading [this](https://askubuntu.com/a/312216/220228) answer I ran `dmesg | grep "EXT4-fs error"` to see if I have any issues related to the filesystem / journaling system itself.

It returned many times:
`[68241.757233] EXT4-fs error (device vda): htree_dirblock_to_tree:892: inode #533953: block 2108070: comm updatedb.mlocat: bad entry in directory: rec_len is smaller than minimal - offset=0(0), inode=0, rec_len=0, name_len=0`

What should I do?

Answer (score 0):

I rebooted ubuntu, it asked me if I want to solve some problems, I said yes and it did solve them.